# Can biblatex-publist omit names which include middle initials without omitting all names which share my surname?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

I was putting together a publication list today. I started by copying it from my CV where I have always managed the list manually. However, I recently noticed `biblatex-publist` so I thought I would give that a go.

This question concerns the first of three problems I encountered. From my point of view, this is also the most fundamental.

One key feature of the package is that it allows you to omit your own name from the list of authors for publications, as is usual when making a list. However, I cannot get this to work well because I publish using 'FirstName MiddleInitial. Surname' so that `author` is specified as `Surname, First M.`. If I ask for all names with my surname to be omitted, it works fine. However, I have a really common surname so this isn't a good solution. (It would work for this case but I don't want to rely on it.) Yet any attempt I make to specify my first name - e.g. as `First` or as `First M.` doesn't omit my name at all.

I'm not sure if I've misunderstood the syntax but I experimented with the name of a coauthor who does not use a middle initial, and specifying both surname and first name worked as expected in that case. So it definitely has to do with the middle initial, it seems.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist,backend=biber]{biblatex}
  \omitname[Me I.]{Mine}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{my-article,
      author = {Mine, Me I.},
      title = {Paper I Wrote},
      journal = {Some Journal},
      year = 1022,
      pages = {99--117},
      volume = 45,
      number = 2}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{my-article}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: Reference list still including omitted author's name]

I also tried the following with the same results:

```
\omitname[Me]{Mine}
```

Is there an easy way to correct this so that the omission works even for authors who use middle initials to publish?

Note that I am not especially attached to `biblatex-publist`. If there's an alternative method, that would be fine. (Especially true since this is not the only difficulty I have using `biblatex-publist` so an alternative might well be preferable!)

Comment: From looking at `publist.bbx`, it seems that middle initials are not handled explicitly.  Something in the `\bpl@normalize` macro is handling the spaces in the bibtex version of the "Firstname MI." sequence differently than it does what is passed to `\omitname`.  I suspect an email to Jürgen Spitzmüller would clear things up, though...

Comment: Not the nicest workaround, but try `\omitname[Me\bibnamedelima I.]{Mine}`. You can see what `biblatex` makes of the names in the `.bbl` file, here `Mine, Me I.` becomes `\name{labelname}{1}{}{{{hash=41274140480afc1dcd1fc7fc1b6f2529}{Mine}{M\bibinitperiod}{Me\bibnamedelima I.}{M\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim I\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}}`. `biblatex-publist` seems to check against the full first name and last name, not hashes. So we have to replicate the exact "name" in the `.bbl` file. Maybe use of hashes is worth a feature request to Jürgen Spitzmüller.

Comment: @moewe is right - you should use hashes to do this really

Comment: @PLK Just out of interest: Is there a way to get the hash of a name on the fly in a document (without necessarily having that particular name in a `.bib` file or referring to a particular entry in the `.bib` file as in `\citefield{my-article}{namehash}`), such as `\gethash{Mine, Me I.}`?

Comment: @PLK You mean `biblatex-publist` should or I, as the end-user, should? If the latter, how would I do that?

Comment: @moewe Thanks. That looks very helpful as a workaround. I should have thought to look in the `.bbl` rather than just the `bbx`.

Comment: I mean `biblatex-publist` should compare using the name hashes.

Comment: @PLK Thanks. I sent an email earlier to the author requesting this as a feature. Hopefully...

Comment: @PLK can you tell me how I would _generate_ a proper namehash within the bbx file from what the user input in the \omitname macro? I do not quite understand how I would create the hash for comparison.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. You can't do that in the .bbx since biber creates the hashes. You could potentially make `\omitname` take a citekey of as argument which points to a `dataonly` .bib entry containing the name you want. Then it would be in the .bbl so you could get the hash but would not be in the bibliography?

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this, too. However, I do not want to break the UI. And it turned out I can _normalize_ away the bibnamedelims quite easily. Let's see if this suffices.

Comment: @JSpitzm I've been wondering whether this would be better implemented in `biblatex`. Publication lists are not the only place this comes up and authors and editors are not the only fields which need to be omitted. For example, preparing a paper for blind review is another place where similar sorts of issues emerge. I'm just wondering if some sort of functionality could be provided in `biblatex` to make this sort of thing easier.

Comment: @cfr I suppose you need to ask the biblatex developers.

Answer (score 2):

If we have a look at the `.bbl` file (as created by Biber) we can see that the simple `author = {Mine, Me I.}` becomes (line breaks were inserted for readability)

```
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{hash=41274140480afc1dcd1fc7fc1b6f2529}
     {Mine}
     {M\bibinitperiod}
     {Me\bibnamedelima I.}
     {M\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim I\bibinitperiod}
     {}{}{}{}}%
  }
```

As far as `biblatex` is concerned, the first name of "Mine, Me I." is `Me\bibnamedelima I.`, so we have to check against that name:

```
\omitname[Me\bibnamedelima I.]{Mine}
```

Full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\omitname[Me\bibnamedelima I.]{Mine}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{my-article,
  author  = {Mine, Me I.},
  title   = {Paper I Wrote},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = 1022,
  pages   = {99--117},
  volume  = 45,
  number  = 2,
}
@article{my-article-w,
  author  = {Mine, Me I. and von Last, Jr, First},
  title   = {Paper I Wrote With Someone Else},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = 1023,
  pages   = {23--45},
  volume  = 2,
  number  = 5,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{my-article,my-article-w}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For `.bbl` files created by BibTeX, `author = {Mine, Me I.}` becomes

```
\name{author}{1}{}{%
  {{}%
   {Mine}{M.}%
   {Me~I.}{M.~I.}%
   {}{}%
   {}{}}%
}
```

consequently, we have to `\omitname[Me~I.]{Mine}` here.

---

Until `biblatex-publist` uses hashes to compare names your best bet is to look up the name as formatted in the `.bbl` file and copy the first and last name from there to the `\omitname` macro.

Also be aware of the fact that currently `biblatex-publist` only compares first and last names and not Jr./von (pre and suffix) parts, so you might end up omitting too much (in very rare cases).

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with the problem differently, since it is not possible to use name hashes with the current UI of the package. In version 0.9 of the package (on its way to CTAN just now), the problem should be fixed. Also, I have added a second optional argument to `\omitname` for name prefix (aka von-part).